# Sticky Header in ListView

Tags: android, listview

Could anyone please tell me how to add sticky header to list view?

```
<se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: I believe you can read the implementation in the Documentation. https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: @ toshkinl, Actually i was following that... but i got errors... Could you please help me?

Comment: If you provide more of your code - errors/adapter I would be able to try helping.